# What does Unknown Hard Error mean?

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I've been getting numerous STOP errors for a while now on my computer with Win7 SP1. I just rolled it back to a point in February, before the errors started happening.

Some include **UNKNOWN HARD ERROR**, **IRQL DRIVERS NOT LESS OR EQUAL**, and **PAGE FAULT ON NONPAGED AREA**.

For about a week the errors were almost nonexistent. Then the BSODs started happening today after using the computer for 15 minutes, then 5 minute, then 1 minute, and now seemingly instantly after choosing a user. I tried running it safe mode. No luck. Last known good config- zilch. I haven't done anything to the computer as in fatal changes. Any help? I can't access the computer AT ALL.

[image]

I edited it in PopAGraph so you could see the error clearly. I turned off Auto Restart after crash so I could take a picture, and THAT welcomed me home from vacation.

I haven't changed anything in the WINDOWS folder etc... but now that I think of it the BSODs started happening when my 5 y/o brother was on it one morning when I wasn't awake yet.  (as noted before, around February)

Comment: Check heatsinks are well attached and fans are running well and not clogged with crud. A rapidly deteriorating machine could have a heat problem. Can you boot from a Linux LiveCD at all? That would at least give you an idea if your Windows is hosed as if Linux can run fine then the majority of the hardware will be be established as probably okay.

Comment: @DavidPostill It's an image on my iPad, so I'm not sure I can link it. Also, no, I can't boot into safe mode. Well, I can, but I get a BSOD immediately after choosing a user and entering their password.

Comment: [Test your memory modules using this software](http://www.memtest.org/), let it run for several hours, see if it shows any errors, you may have a bad memory module.

Comment: @Moab I'm not sure if I can access the computer _now_, but I'll try this if I can. I used Windows Memory Diagnostic, and it says "My computer has a memory problem" and that I should "contact the manufacturer".

Comment: Ok, it has a memory problem which means one or more of your memory modules needs replaced. You have answered your own question.

Comment: @moab Ok, thanks. How would I replace the module? And why did you only comment on my question? Wouldn't it be smarter to answer it through an answer?

Comment: @lucs100, Because I was making an educated guess.

Comment: @Moab Edited the post

Comment: @Mokubai Edited the post

Comment: @DavidPostill Edited the post

Comment: @lucs100 [Bug Check 0x109: CRITICAL_STRUCTURE_CORRUPTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557228%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: There are generally three different causes for this bug check: 1/  A driver has inadvertently, or deliberately, modified critical kernel code or data. <snip> 2/ A developer attempted to set a normal kernel breakpoint using a kernel debugger that was not attached when the system was started. <snip> 3/ A hardware corruption occurred. For example, the kernel code or data could have been stored in memory that failed.

Comment: Memory failure looks the most likely given you other comment re Windows Memory Diagnostic